# Change background colour for each array element

Tags: javascript

Having this code, been trying to implement a function but got stuck. The purpose would be that each time you press "Next" and a new flashcard is displayed, it should have a new background colour. As you see, the elements of the flashcards are displayed through an array. I tried to add a new array and increment at the same time with the next-card, but got stuck :/ .

Comment: I don’t see any additional array. Show us what you “got stuck” with at least.

Comment: It was a mess and i've deleted it entirely as it provoked me headaches, lol. The stuck part is about the entire problem of changing the background of an array element (and more of that), as i've done my research about related questions here,before asking it, and found nothing.
But, i thank you anyway for asking and for your interest. <3

Comment: Just in case it is data you want to use... It is "Das Frühstück"

Comment: Why did you delete from your question so much of what seemed helpful or even relevant information? Especially code is usually much appreciated by users here.

Comment: Um. It had -3 votes and did my best to review the question to lift the bans, as i am new and not sure why people down-voted. I had in mind, tho, that the snippets still exist in user's comments :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const colors = ["#000","#667eea","#764ba2"];
function getColor() { 
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
}
```

I added this in clicknext and clickprevious

```
  accordion_toggle.css({"background": 
  "linear-gradient(135deg, "+getColor()+ " 0%, " + getColor()+" 100%)"});
```

```js
var idioms = [
    "Das Fruhstuck <br><br>  ",
    "Strawberry",
    "Das Auto <br><br> ",
    "Car",
    "Der Stuhl<br><br> ",
    "Chair",
    "Die Jacke<br><br>  ",
    "The Jacket",
    "Der asd<br><br>‍",
    "asd",
    "test<br><br>  ",
    "test1"
]
;

var index = 0;
var increment = 2;
var $accordion_toggle = $('#accordion-toggle');
var $accordion_content = $('#accordion-content');

function incrementIndex () {
    index += increment;
        
    if (index >= idioms.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}

function decrementIndex () {
    index -= increment;
        
    if (index < 0) {
        index = (idioms.length - increment);
    }
}

const colors = ["#000","#667eea","#764ba2"];
function getColor() { 
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
}

function updateIdioms () {
    $accordion_toggle.html(idioms[index]);
    $accordion_content.html(idioms[index + 1]);
}

function onNextClick () {   
        $accordion_toggle.css({"background": "linear-gradient(135deg, "+getColor()+" 0%, "+getColor()+" 100%)"});        
     $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        incrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
     });
     
}


function onPreviousClick () {
    $accordion_toggle.css({"background": "linear-gradient(135deg, "+getColor()+" 0%, "+getColor()+" 100%)"});        
    $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        decrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
    });
}

$(function () {
    updateIdioms();
    
    $('#Next').click(onNextClick);
    $('#Previous').click(onPreviousClick);

    $accordion_toggle.click(function () {
        $accordion_content.slideToggle('fast'); 
    });
});
```

```css
#accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;

  /* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-11-13 13:16:23
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

  /**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation flip-horizontal-bottom
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
  @-webkit-keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
      transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
      transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
  }
}

#accordion-toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;

  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-2px);


}

@import url ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap");


#accordion-content {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;

}

#accordion-content.default {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}



#accordion {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip-horizontal-bottom {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="accordion" >
<h3>Click on the next button to see the next idioms in German. Click on the idiom to see the equivalent in English</h3>
<br>
    <h4 id="accordion-toggle"></h4>
    <div id="accordion-content">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    
<div align="center">
<br>
</div>


<button id="Next" >Next card</button>
</div> </body>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, but i should've express myself better. The element i want to change is accordion toggle ( the green-ish card with german words). I've adapted the code you gave to me for it, but it is not changing when i press Next Card, only when i press on it literally.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your `onNextClick()` function

```
function changeColor() {
    var randomColor = () => Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    const element = document.getElementById('accordion-toggle');
    element.style.background = `linear-gradient(135deg, #${randomColor()} 0%, #${randomColor()} 100%)`;
}
```

Above function will generate a randon color and apply to the element. You could also make the fuction generic in order to apply the same to the hidden card.

```js
var idioms = [
    "Das Frushstuck <br><br>  ",
    "Strawberry",
    "Das Auto <br><br> ",
    "Car",
    "Der Stuhl<br><br> ",
    "Chair",
    "Die Jacke<br><br>  ",
    "The Jacket",
    "Der asd<br><br>‍",
    "asd",
    "test<br><br>  ",
    "test1"
]
;

var index = 0;
var increment = 2;
var $accordion_toggle = $('#accordion-toggle');
var $accordion_content = $('#accordion-content');

function incrementIndex () {
    index += increment;
        
    if (index >= idioms.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}

function changeColor() {
    var randomColor = () => Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    const element = document.getElementById('accordion-toggle');
    element.style.background = `linear-gradient(135deg, #${randomColor()} 0%, #${randomColor()} 100%)`;
}

function decrementIndex () {
    index -= increment;
        
    if (index < 0) {
        index = (idioms.length - increment);
    }
}

function updateIdioms () {
    $accordion_toggle.html(idioms[index]);
    $accordion_content.html(idioms[index + 1]);
}

function onNextClick () {   
     $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        incrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
        changeColor();
     });
     
}


function onPreviousClick () {
    $accordion_content.slideUp(function () {
        decrementIndex();
        updateIdioms();
    });
}

$(function () {
    updateIdioms();
    
    $('#Next').click(onNextClick);
    // $('#Next').click(changeColor);
    $('#Previous').click(onPreviousClick);

    $accordion_toggle.click(function () {
        $accordion_content.slideToggle('fast'); 
    });
});
```

```css
#accordion-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;

  /* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-11-13 13:16:23
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */

  /**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation flip-horizontal-bottom
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
  @-webkit-keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
      transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
      transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
      transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
  }
}

#accordion-toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;

  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #d4fc79 0%, #96e6a1 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-2px);


}

@import url ("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap");


#accordion-content {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;

}

#accordion-content.default {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}



#accordion {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flip-horizontal-bottom {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="accordion" >
<h3>Click on the next button to see the next idioms in German. Click on the idiom to see the equivalent in English</h3>
<br>
    <h4 id="accordion-toggle"></h4>
    <div id="accordion-content">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    
<div align="center">
<br>
</div>


<button id="Next" >Next card</button>
</div> </body>
```